# Showing different header based on variable in report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My company is switching to Jasper reports from Microsoft RS, so we are converting reports to jasper, these reports often have multiple headers which are shown based on parametars passed.In RS when you hide the row(s) whole table jumps up, leaving no empty space. How is this done in JR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jasper there is a property called **Print When Expression** I think it will help you

Comment: I know about it, but would it shrink the page if I do it with few text fields in middle of report?

Comment: I used it for columns. It worked very well.  can't you apply the same property for the text fields?

Comment: It works, but it will leave you with blank space where hidden header was, unless you mark "Remove line when blank", this can get annoying when you want to print blank line as part of header. A better approach is using bands and putting Print When Expression on whole band, but you can't use band on page header.

Comment: Try to avoid detail band for table data